# Filtering results by form select dropdown, based on HTML 5 Geo Location

Tags: php, html, location, geo, city

I have a simple form select drop down that filters rows by cities. Now what I am trying to do is to filter those results based on user's location.  I recently learned that you can get a user's location(long, lat) using HTML Geo Location.  Below is the script that does that.

However, I am a little lost on how I can use that with my PHP code that retrieves rows from MySQl database, based on the selected city?

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var x = document.getElementById("demo");

   function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError);
    } else { 
     x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
   }

   function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
   }

   function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
     case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      x.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
      break;
     case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      x.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
      break;
     case error.TIMEOUT:
      x.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
      break;
     case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      x.innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred."
      break;
    }
   }
   
   getLocation();
   showPosition(position);
   }); 
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to post the data you've received over to a php script via an ajax call.

Here's just an example, but you should be able to work with it from there:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var contact = $("#contact").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email + '&password1='+ password + '&contact1='+ contact;
if(name==''||email==''||password==''||contact=='')
{
  alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
 // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
       data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(result){
       alert(result);
}
});
}
 return false;
});
});
```